# Visual studio doesn't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Last friday everything worked perfect. But on Monday I got this error message in Visual Studio.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1.
```

Doesn't matter what I do that I always get same error. I've repaired VS , uninstalled VS , changed the SDK , the plugins.. everything. If I execute cl.exe manually I dont get any error.

Have found this thread:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/724154/error-msb6006-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819

I thought It was written by me! but there's no solution inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the source code that causes this?

Comment: It is a big project , lot of classes dont know wich one do that.. but any project work, all of them crashes , they dont compile.

Comment: Pre/Post build script.

Comment: What you mean? Dont understand it.

Comment: I've been the whole week trying things, anyone can help me!?

Comment: Is your project under version control? can you go a step back?

Comment: It is, I tried and was for nothing. I also tried to go back restoring to a back windows point but It didnt succed. The project didnt change during the weekend, on friday when I shut down the pc was working and on monday was not.

Answer (score 0):

The important parts of this message are:

CL.EXE : This means the error occurs during a compilation step. It's not a pre-build step.
Code -1 : This means the error is not the same as the one you linked (which was -1073741819).

The first thing to do is figuring out *when* it fails. What file is being compiled? Create the default "Hello, World" project and compile that. If it works: problem is input dependent. If not: what's the problematic input? Can you compile a single file of your project? If you can't find any, pick one and turn on "pre-processing only". Does it at least pass the pre-processor phase? Turn on LTCG. (link-time code generation, CL won't create x86 code). Does it work now?